# How to implement a generic HTTP service in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

In my angular module I wrote a generic http handler for all my ajax requests.'

I was expecting that I could use the service across controllers, but my problem is the promise seems to be global.

Once `ControllerOne` uses the `mapi_loader` service, when I load `AnotherController` (by `ng-click="go('/$route_to_load_another_controller')"`), `AnotherController` is loaded a promise that has already returned from `ControllerOne` even though the URL they `fetch` are totally different.

So I guess my question is how do I write a service I could use across controllers? Do I really need to write a separate service for each controller where their only difference in code is the URL passed for `$http.jsonp`?

```
angular.module('myAppControllers',[])
  .service('mapi_loader', ['$http', function($http) {
    var promise;
    var myService = {
      fetch: function(url) {
        if ( !promise ) {
          promise = $http.jsonp(url)
          .then(function (response) {
            return response.data.nodes;
          });
        }
        return promise;
      }
    };
    return myService;
  }])
  .controller('ControllerOne', ['$scope', 'mapi_loader', function ($scope, mapi_loader) {
    mapi_loader
    .fetch("http://host.com/mapi_data_for_controller_one?callback=JSON_CALLBACK")
    .then(function(data) {
      $scope.useme = data;
    });
  }])
  .controller('AnotherController', ['$scope', 'mapi_loader', function ($scope, mapi_loader) {
    mapi_loader
    .fetch("http://host.com/mapi_data_for_another_controller?callback=JSON_CALLBACK")
    .then(function(data) {
      $scope.useme = data;
    });
  }])
;
```

Comment: Just move your promise into the scope of the function.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
angular.module('myAppControllers',[])
  .service('mapi_loader', function($http) {
    var alreadyLoading = {};
    return {
      fetch: function(url) {
        if ( url in alreadyLoading ) {
          return alreadyLoading[url];
        }
        return alreadyLoading[url] = $http.jsonp(url)
         .then(function (response) {
           delete alreadyLoading[url];
           return response.data.nodes;
        });
      }
    };
  })
  .controller('ControllerOne', function ($scope, mapi_loader) {
    ...
  })
  .controller('AnotherController', function ($scope, mapi_loader) {
    ...
  });
```